# Can I live preview React components in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

New to React. I have been using live server for html files in VS Code but I can't seem to find the same functionality for React components (.js files). Maybe it's obvious or I'm looking for the wrong thing.

I'd like to make changes in the component, especially MUI styling and see the incremental results in a live preview, rather than the entire application having to refresh and click back to the form I'm working on. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You could use Storybook for this.https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at this but kind of confused. Do I need to change my code to use it?

Comment: I've been building a tool that does exactly this :) You can try it out at https://reactpreview.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to change your code when using storybook. You just have to write new files, that import your component. Then you can pass it fake props to see how it behave depending in many scenarios. If you use create-react-app, it super easy to install, if you have your own config, then your level is good enough to follow their tutorial. The files are formatted like this: `MyComponent.stories.js` . Then storybook will look at all files that contains "stories" in their name, and launch them on port 6006 when you write `yarn/npm run storybook` in your terminal. I highly recommend storybook, it is used by most of companies.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find a satisfactory solution and not willing to invest too much. Storybook looks like I'd have to change my code and because I'm still relatively new to react, not sure I'm up for that.

I'm just letting VSCode restart server each time I save a change then going to the browser and clicking through the menus to get to the page I'm working on.

For more complex ui changes, I'll create a code sandbox mini react app and just work on that for, like css changes, etc.

UPDATE:
I've implemented Storybook and I like it. After following the doc to install it I saw that I just needed to create a file (story) for a component like MyComponent.stories.js and put in the few lines of code to import and use it, passing in whatever props I wanted to see.

I decided to put my stories files into a separate separate stories folder under src. Here's an example for a Details component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import Details from '../Details';

// How to display the component in Storybook page
export default {
  title: 'Details',
  component: Details,
  // Our exports that end in "Data" are not stories.
  excludeStories: /.*Data$/
};

// Props passed into component
export const recordData = {
  record: {
    id: '1',
    createdOn: '2020-04-20 4:07 PM',
    createdBy: 'dgarv',
    modifiedOn: '2020-04-20 4:07 PM',
    modifiedBy: 'dgarv',
  }
};

// Use the actual component
export const Default = () => <Details {...recordData} />;
```

Comment: Ok. You've convinced me to use Storybook. One more thing to learn, but it does look easy and very useful. Thanks for steering me in that right direction. Wish I could figure out how to give you credit for the answer??

Comment: If my comment has been helpful, you can mark it as the correct answer to this topic. This way, people who have the same question will see this is a solved thread and find their happiness here. I'll copy paste my comment as an answer so you can approve it if you want. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed an extension named AutoPreview that you can use it to preview React/Vue component in VS Code.

You can get it in extension market: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jawei.autopreviewer&ssr=false#overview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Preview.js to see the rendered code - https://previewjs.com/docs/platforms/vscode